# The subject for "seeing" in a sentence

Tags: grammar

I can't figure out what's the subject for "seeing" in the sentence below:

- Seeing some foods and beverages being consumed on, or hearing them mentioned on, television programs increase the likelihood that viewers will consume similar kinds of foods and beverages.

Taking it as a reduced relative clause, I thought the omitted subject for "seeing" is "television programs". This was how my trouble began.

Any helps would be greatly appreciated!

Leon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is a reduced form, and the omitted subject is probably "viewers" or "people". Thy meaning is that when people see food and drink consumed, or hear food mentioned, it is more likely that those viewers will eat and drink similar things.

Bu the way, the verb should be "increases" not "increase". One says "seeing A increases Y." Makign the subject complex does not make it plural, so "Seeing A or hearing B increases Y."

Comment: Thank you so much. Would you mind explaining what would be the complete sentence if it were not a reduced form?